# Best place to check conditions and redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, page-lifecycle

What is the best part of the page lifecycle to check if a condition is true and redirect away from the page that is load if it is. In this case i am checking if the user has set his/her account settings after signup. If they have not then i redirect. However i would like to perform the check and redirect before the page in questions begin actually loading.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the variable condition stored? You may be able to "fail faster", depending - such as on [`PreInit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.preinit.aspx), prior to any extraneous page processing. To do this on a global level, look into the [`HttpApplication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.aspx) class and the [`BeginRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest.aspx) (or similar) event: you will need to filter for the particular request types (pages), though.

Comment: Then you probably don't need to wait until the page is fully loaded to do the redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct place to put that logic would be in the Page_Load method

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Check for condition here & redirect if needed

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
          //Load data & bind stuff here
        }
     }
```

Comment: What about globally for every page of the site?

Comment: slfan is right..if you want to do it on every page you can add checks to those methods in the global.asax. Other options are putting them in your master pages or a Base Page class(if you use them on every page).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have to check this for every page. In this case I would use an event in Global.asax, e.g.

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

or (in case it has to do with authentication)

```
    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

If you only have to check it after login, you could implement an event handler for OnLoggedIn.

A third possibility would be to implement an abstract common base page for all your asp.net forms and implement the OnPageLoad event. This is better than to copy the code in every page.